# Extracting out a line from the source of a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose I have a website, say http://example.com. Now I want to design a website, and there I need some information from example.com. For example, using HTML/Javascript/JQuery can I take out a specific line from the source of the website and store it in a string in my coding?

For example, suppose the 35th line in the code of example.com is:- `<h3> Welcome user</h3>`. So in a string in my code I want to store "`<h3>Welcome user</h3>`". How can I do it? Any suggestions?

Comment: No code, no details, and potentially nefarious, -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to cross-domain restrictions, JavaScript cannot access the other server. However, you can access your own server and have something like PHP do the work:

```php
echo file("http://example.com/")[34];
```

However, do you really want to be doing this? After all, any change to the website (which you don't appear to control) will destroy your code, and they could even inject something there, like this:

```
<script>if(location.hostname != "example.com") kill_the_browser_slowly();</script>
```

I would think you'd be much better off parsing the DOM, like so:

```php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents("http://example.com/"));
$h3 = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h3')->item(0);
if( !$h3) echo "<h3>Can't find the header</h3>";
else echo $dom->saveHTML($h3);
```

Comment: Thanks! However this technique will not work if the other website is not in my own server or if it does not give me the permission to do that will it?

Comment: The only reason for this to not work is if the other site has blocked requests that send no User-Agent or send a specific one that is blacklisted. Other than that, if your browser can access it, then so can your server.

Comment: Replace `echo` with `$somevar = `

Comment: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Comment: It does exactly what it says on the tin: Get the `h3` elements by their tag name, and fetches the first item of that list.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible using only jQuery/Javascript/HTML. You'd need to rely on some server-side technology for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this without a serverside scripting language like node.js or php or any other server side language.

Reason: To make a request from your page to another page from JavaScript you must use AJAX which , unless using CORS( must be allowed by the page you copy) , you can't run on another domain. AJAX requests are usually bound to the domain they originate from,

Comment: Do you want to say that to do this the website from which I am copying the information should give me the permission?

Comment: @user2517072 not only to you. CORS is applied by adding some extra headers that imply that the content of the page may be accessed with AJAX. 99% of the websites do not add them. I recommend using a server-side technology.